# Hide elements when searching for <li> inside a <ul>

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code where I have an input and I can search for `<li>` elements inside a `<ul>`. It's working like a charm, however, I also have "button" (that will work as a title and accordion in the future) elements inside the same div as the `<ul>` and when I filter the `<li>` elements the button remains (obviously)

I want the button to also disappear when I hide the `<li>` elements that I don't want to see. For example, if I search for "Adele" I also want to hide the button "D TO F", since it's an element from a `<ul>` I'm not using, meaning I want all the div to disappear. (tried to be as clear as possible).

Any help would be appreciated! Code below:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // get all of the li elements that are contained by "myUL" elements
    document.querySelectorAll(".myUL li")
    // iterate over them 
      .forEach(l => l
      // toggle the "hidden" class on those li items that have
        .classList.toggle("hidden",
        // an anchor tag whose text includes the text typed into the textbox
          !l.querySelector("a").textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)));

}
```

```css
  .hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<div class=hide-box>
  <button>A TO C</button>
<ul class="myUL">
    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Anne</a></li>
  
    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  
    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  
<div class=hide-box>
  <button>D TO F</button>
      <ul class="myUL">
        <li><a href="#">Daniel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Danielle</a></li>
      
        <li><a href="#">Ernest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eric</a></li>
      
        <li><a href="#">Fabio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ferdinand</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Frederick</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, if below answers help, feel free to mark one of them as answers so that question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the parent `<div>`s ids related to the button text/info you want to filter, and hide the entire div with your filter.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to fix it is to insert the button to the list.
Then on the iteration you need to change `a` to `*` - meaning all elements inside the list item.

Something like that:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    document.querySelectorAll(".myUL li")
      .forEach(l => l.classList.toggle("hidden",!l.querySelector("*").textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)));}
```

```css
.acoBtn { list-style: none}
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<div class=hide-box>
  
  <ul class="myUL">
    <li class="acoBtn"><button>A TO C</button></li>
    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Anne</a></li>
  
    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  
    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  
<div class=hide-box>
      <ul class="myUL">
        <li class="acoBtn"><button>D TO F</button></li>
        <li><a href="#">Daniel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Danielle</a></li>
      
        <li><a href="#">Ernest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eric</a></li>
      
        <li><a href="#">Fabio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ferdinand</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Frederick</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: OP mentions of using the buttons as accordion in future. Placing them in li might not be a good option

Answer (score 0):

Just add below snippet :

```
document.querySelectorAll(".hide-box")
    .forEach(d => d
    .classList.toggle("hidden",
            ([...d.querySelectorAll('.myUL li')]
        .every(l => l.classList.contains("hidden"))
      )
    )     
)
```

in your function making your complete function look like :

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // get all of the li elements that are contained by "myUL" elements
    document.querySelectorAll(".myUL li")
    // iterate over them 
      .forEach(l => l
      // toggle the "hidden" class on those li items that have
        .classList.toggle("hidden",
        // an anchor tag whose text includes the text typed into the textbox
          !l.querySelector("a").textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)));

// Code that checks if all li in the ul of a given div are hidden then hide entire div as well
   document.querySelectorAll(".hide-box")
        .forEach(d => d
        .classList.toggle("hidden",
                ([...d.querySelectorAll('.myUL li')]
            .every(l => l.classList.contains("hidden"))
          )
        )     
    )

}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxL570rd/3/)